# VB 2010 Using DISTINCT in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

using vb 2010 on an access database

```
INSERT INTO UniqueTable
SELECT DISTINCT 
          1,2,3,4,5
FROM DataTable
```

This will get only unique rows in all fields and if I only specify the one field I want to be distinct it only inserts the data in that field

How can I import all data from every field where field 5 is unique?

If I set the database field properties to not allow duplicates all import fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use distinct in this case, you can't specify which field need to be distinct, it works for entire columns selected. Use group by instead, like: `..GROUP BY 5 .. HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`. That will return all rows having field 5 value appear only once in the table, in other word distinct.